# Do empty/constant strings take less space in Parquet on Hive?

Tags: hive, parquet

If I have a very large table with string fields, how well are they compressed in the following two use cases? Does Parquet save on storage space in these cases?

1. Empty strings
2. A constant value (identical for all fields)

Comment: Parquet uses dictionary encoding so it should be able to compress efficiently identical values. I recommend experimenting with it and comparing file sizes. See https://parquet.apache.org/docs/file-format/data-pages/encodings/

Comment: I just finished running this experiment, and I can see that the dictionary works as expected. Don't you want to write your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

1 - empty string - less space - Same I/O - less network transfer - *Recommended*
2 - same string- more spaces to store- Little higher I/O - more network transfer

Parquet is a columns storage file format. Which means, columns stored in row groups, header and footer. Each row group contains data from the same columns. The same columns are stored together in each row group.

This means, empty columns will uses less space but not a lot. So, data transfer would be higher for constant values.

Comment: I'm not sure you understood my intent - I'm not choosing between an empty or null column - I have both, and I'm wondering how much I could save by removing them. But as @0x26res wrote, because Parquet uses a dictionary, it turns out these columns take almost no space at all

Comment: Your question says, compare empty string vs constant value. I tried to answer per that.